# how to make an ESD sensitive circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, protection, esd

I have an experiment where I plug a sensor to an ESD (Electrostatic Discharge) protection circuit. Sensors are very expensive and very sensitive to ESD.
I have tested my protection circuit it is working fine. I was wondering what is an easy way to build a ESD sensitive device, so every time I test my ESD protection circuit, I don't plug my expensive sensor to test. I want to have an alternative to my sensor, for example something that if I touch when I'm not grounded, would blow or show me that it is sensitive to ESD. OR in general would let me know that the environment has some static charges.

I'm not an expert in circuits, I have googled my question and found very complex circuits. I would like to hear your opinions.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sounds like you need an ESD matt that is grounded, a wrist strap to ground you to the matt, and an ESD tester to ensure your strap is working.  https://www.amazon.com/s?k=esd+mat+tester&ref=nb_sb_noss_1

Comment: Your question is unclear because you haven't provided any specifications. Do you also have a preferred topology for your circuit? If you're making this device, these are things to keep in mind.

Comment: Guys:  The question is pretty clear.  Racaio has **built** an ESD protection circuit for a sensor, and would like to test the protection circuit **by itself.**  What can be used to **measure** the effects of an ESD incident that hits the protection circuit.

Comment: You can just use the gate-source on a small MOSFET. Apply ESD to the gate and then test to see if gate-source becomes shorted. I would just scope it directly but you need a high bandwidth scope.

Answer (score 1):

What we did was to use 100x or 1000x scope probes and watch the signal on the scope.
If you don't have high voltage probes, then you can make some fairly easily with some resistors, but I would stick to only ESD, which is low power, nothing with substantial power behind it.

[how to make 100x scope probe](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_make_a_100X_oscilloscope_probe)
Or
[EEV video blog](https://youtu.be/jUvSP3BQpvs)

Be aware that ESD, if not from a controlled source, can vary wildly depending on environmental conditions (mainly humidity), and can reach 200kV.

Answer (score 0):

try this; the large capacitor is there to integrate the charge and thus stretch out the pulse so even SLOW ADC sampling can record the total charge.

The Human Body Model has rather small total charge storage, which is unloaded onto the victim circuit thru 1.5Kohm resistor in the TESTER.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd7QWY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why the downvote?